# Why Is Angled Line In 'Pie Slice' Not Drawing Correctly With UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying draw a 'pie slice' in a circle, where one edge is vertical from the top to the center, one edge is an arc from the top point to a point on the circle, and the last edge is from the end of the arc to the center.

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
class ArcView : UIView {
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let x1 = rect.minX
    let x2 = rect.maxX
    let y1 = rect.minY
    let y2 = rect.maxY

    let arc_radius = self.superview!.frame.width/2
    let delta_y = y2-y1
    let delta_x = x2-x1
    let angle = asin(delta_x/arc_radius)

    let center = CGPoint(x:x1, y:y2)
    let top = CGPoint(x:x1, y:y1)

    //draw path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: top)
    path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: arc_radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: angle, clockwise: true)
    path.addLine(to: center)
    path.addLine(to: top)
    path.close()


    UIColor.green.setFill()
    path.fill()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
  }
```

And when I try to draw this within a given rectangle, this is what I am getting:
[image: Where the green section is the view I am making with the class above.]

Where the green section is the view I am making with the class above. I like the arc and the vertical line, but I want there to be only one other edge which is a line from the right point of the arc to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your top and center calculation is wrong.

Instead of

```
let center = CGPoint(x:x1, y:y2)
let top = CGPoint(x:x1, y:y1)
```

Try

```
let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX y:rect.midY
let top = CGPoint(x:x1, y:rect.midY)
```

Comment: My names are a little weird in this limited context, but 'center' refers to the center of the circle, which is another view, and the bounding rectangle of the arcview object runs along that center vertically. So it is a good idea, but does not quite work.